# Show a single cell data from sql

Tags: php, sql

Php and sql is new to me.So I face a simple problem.

My table name is student_table(id,s_name).Now I want to select the id of 'Shakib'.

My code :

```
<?php
        $username="root";
        $password="";
        $database="mydb";
        mysql_connect('localhost',$username,$password);
        @mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");

        $query2="SELECT id from student_table where s_name = 'Shakib'";
        $result2=mysql_query($query2);

        echo $result2;
```

When I run this code it shows "Resource id #4" . 
Please help me how I can show the id of 'Shakib'?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$query=mysql_query($query2);
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
   echo $row['id'];
}
```

According to php docs:

```
 mysql_query() sends a unique query (multiple queries are not supported) to
 the currently active database on the server that's associated with the
 specified link_identifier.
```

It doesn't executes the query `"Resource id #4` is actually the reference to that query. To execute that query and get the result you have to use `mysql_fetch_array`.

Comment: @IKR My Pleasure, You can accept an answer if you think it was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If you are expecting only one row result then you can use:

```
$id = mysql_result($result2,0,0);
```